# How to use Findall(closure) in grails project

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I've been trying to add search functionality to my grails project and I'm running into a bit of a snag.

Here's my domain class

```
class Worker{
    String name
}
```

and here's my controller

```
package main

class SiteController {

    def search()
    {
        def results = Worker.findAll{
            it.name ==~ /.*John.*/
        }

        [results:results]
    }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to use the findAll(closure) function, but I can't find examples anywhere and I can't seam to figure it out via testing either, I just want to find all of the workers by the test criteria I put in the closure.

**EDIT 1**

I'm having another problem, for some reason whenever I use any special characters in my regex, such as [. * ?] or any of those, my findAll doesn't return anything.  If I have a workers whose name is "John Smith" and I do

```
name ==~ /John Smith/
```

it works as it should, but if I use any of those special characters such as

```
name ==~ /John.*/
```

or even

```
name ==~ /John S.ith/
```

it won't work, this is very confusing and the regexs works as they should right outside the findall function too, if you could provide some insight into this that'd be very helpful

Comment: Have you tested this query in the Grails console? If I'm not mistaken the regex is dependent of the database that you're using.

Comment: It won't run for me because it says "Groovy:Cannot query property "it" - no such property on class main.Worker exists."

Comment: If I remove the _it_, it runs, but it doesn't actually match what it should.  I have a worker named "John Smith" in my database and nothing shows up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LIKE in query instead, Try this:

> results = Person.findAllByLastNameLike("%John%")

Grails uses hibernate underneath which uses HQL language which is similar to SQL. Alternatively, you can also run full query

> results = Person.findAll("from Person as p where p.lastName LIKE :lastname order by p.lastName",
>                [lastname: '%John%'])

To look for into HQL queries:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html

And it is sad but true, HQL/SQL doesn't support regular expressions, it only supports LIKE clause.

Answer (score 4):

The example [in the docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAll.html) show's that you reference the attribute directly:

```
// Use where criteria (since Grails 2.0)
def results = Person.findAll {
     lastName == "Simpson"
}
```

So applying to your query:

```
def results = Worker.findAll{
  name ==~ /.*John.*/
}
```

Comment: I'm still having some trouble, for some reason regexs with special characters aren't working inside the findAll function, if you could check the edit I made to my question that'd be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think that depends on your SGBD regex, or look at Groovy's regex.